# How can I customize Summernote text editor width?

Tags: summernote

Now I am using [Summernote](http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote) text editor. It is so easy and customizable. But I want to customize width. Example:

```
$("#editor").summernote({
   'width':200px,

});
```

Above code is not effect. How can I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use width like below.

```
$('.editor').summernote({
  width: 150,   //don't use px
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, using the lite version of summernote-0.8.18-dist.zip .

Answer (score 2):

For me it helped to wrap editor with another div with style

```
<div style="width: 80%;">
```